# netstandard 2.1 with .net 4.7 - how to build a common codebase for both?

Tags: .net, .net-standard, net-standard-2.1

With the release coming soon of .net standard 2.1, we are now face with a problem with our codebase, if we want to migrate, we won't be able to share code between our core codebase in netstandard, our android code in xamarin (this will work with netstandard) and our backend (.net 4.7.2).

Because the .net framework will not support any new netstandard implementation, we are faced with a problem, how to share code now accross all those libraries?

Is there any solution around?

The way I think this will be the simplest is having our core codebase target multiple frameworks, maybe netstandard 2.0 and 2.1, or netstandard 2.1 and .net472? What's the best avenue?

Comment: Just don't move to 2.1.  There are few compelling reasons to do so, be sure to read the [what's new](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-standard-2-1/).

Comment: You already have the answers, so what do you want to know further?

Comment: Moving to 2.1 enables EF Core 3.0 across the board. As for my answer, I just wanted to know if it was the best avenue. I mean, having a full solution riddled with #pragma if is about 1000x more complicated than what it was when .netstandard was supported everywhere.

Comment: What Hans said - stick with Standard 2.0 for library code if you can. A .NET Standard which doesn't support the legacy framework is no standard - chances are this time next year they'll be recommending we target .NET (Core) 5 directly. As for EF Core, they relented and the next release - in preview - will target Standard 2.0: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/3.1.0-preview2.19525.5 https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/18141